# Scripting Scaling based on custom properties

Tags: mesh, scripting, objects, scale

I am having an issue, and according to suggestion in my previous question [PREVIOUS POST](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/188104/how-to-replace-object-with-keeping-it-dimmensions-how-to-change-dimension-of-a) I am writing it as another question.

I have a small project where I have a cylinders with custom properties data about Z - Height value, and R - radius Value. I am also having a low poly tree.

I am aiming in `CTRL+L` copy object properties from tree to the cylinder and then accessing scaling with values Z & R from customs.
[image]
I guess that I have to create a simple script for that but I have no idea how to access data in Custom Propoerties of an object.

I feel that it will be something like that after selecting objects:

*bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(type='OBDATA')*

*bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(**R, R, Z**), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)*

I attach my blend file to show the project (part of it) [BLEND FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14YYIZERVTDGy6ghfRVYXh6gvjtctI7or/view?usp=sharing)

The point is I want to easily update vegetation data for city landscape based on true GIS data for shadows and things like that.

If you can please help me write that script properly - will be very glad for help and effort!